# Setup Laravel 8 with Foundation 6

Tags: webpack, sass, zurb-foundation, laravel-8

I'm currently trying to introduce myself with Laravel but got stuck on a strange error regarding Foundation Sites for the front-end part of the page.

By default, Laravel set up the code with bootstrap, so I thought all I need to do is switch the bootstrap stuff by the foundation-sites stuff.

I am doing everything like mentioned in here http://somethingnewtutorial.blogspot.com/2017/07/using-foundation-6-with-laravel-5.html but somehow, when I compile my `app.scss` file to css, all I get is the copyright, but no CSS at all.

Here is my `app.scss`:

```
// Fonts
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');

// Variables
@import 'settings';

// Foundation
@import '~foundation-sites/scss/foundation';
```

And this is the output from `npm run dev`

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito);/**
 * Foundation for Sites
 * Version 6.6.3
 * https://get.foundation
 * Licensed under MIT Open Source
 */
```

That's it. As you can see, the copyright is included, so the file was found. If I type in some simple CSS rules beneath that, they are included as well, but not the mixins (though bootstrap uses them as well and worked!) However, if I change it back to bootstrap like this:

```
// Fonts
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');

// Variables
@import 'settings';

@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

My `app.css` looks just fine like

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito);@charset "UTF-8";

/*!
 * Bootstrap v4.5.2 (https://getbootstrap.com/)
 * Copyright 2011-2020 The Bootstrap Authors
 * Copyright 2011-2020 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/LICENSE)
 */

:root {
  --blue: #007bff;
  --indigo: #6610f2;
  --purple: #6f42c1;
  --pink: #e83e8c;
  --red: #dc3545;
  --orange: #fd7e14;
  --yellow: #ffc107;
  --green: #28a745;
  --teal: #20c997;
  --cyan: #17a2b8;
  --white: #fefefe;
  --gray: #6c757d;
  --gray-dark: #343a40;
  ...
```

My console does not report any errors either

```
> @ development C:\inetpub\wwwroot\laravel\blog
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

98% after emitting SizeLimitsPlugin

 DONE  Compiled successfully in 3594ms                                                                                                                                                                                19:01:11

       Asset       Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
/css/app.css  170 bytes  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app
  /js/app.js   1.56 MiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app
```

So, I am pretty sure I missed something about it, but I have no clue what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed this part from the tute @ [http://somethingnewtutorial.blogspot.com/2017/07/using-foundation-6-with-laravel-5.html][1]:

> At this point we can do 2 things, either reference that file in our
> app.scss directly on node_modules folder or copy it to our
> resources/assets/sass folder. Later option is more suitable in a
> situation where we need to do lots to tweaking. Lets copy that file
> now so that we don't have to dig down to node_modules later when we
> need it.
>
> (c) copy /node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/settings/_settings.scss
> to our resources/assets/sass
>
> (d) Reference this file in our `app.scss`
>
> Remove this line
>
> // Variables @import "variables";
>
> and replace with
>
> // Foundation settings @import "settings";
>
> At this point we can delete the file _variables.scss
>
> (e) Since we copied _settings.scss file to our convenient location,
> lets edit this file.
>
> Change this line
>
> @import 'util/util';
>
> with this one, so that it can reference it correctly
>
> @import "node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/util/util";
>
> (f) From this point we can create other SCSS files as needed and
> import it in our app.scss
>
> …etc